# Receiving emails with sendgrid and cloudmailin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sendgrid, griddler, cloudmailin

I have the same concept as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711476/receiving-and-processing-email-heroku-sendgrid-and-possibly-mailman)(generating a unique random email address for each user in rails app. When the user sends an email that that randomly generated email address, we process the body and store in db.

I followed the following steps:

1. Deployed my app in Heroku
2. Created a sendgrid account and configured the `username` and `password` to heroku(to get the sendgrid addon).
3. added griddler gem and followed the steps mentioned in griddler.
4. Configured the parse webhook in sendgrid with my host and url.

Here comes the main problem:

I registered to coludmailin and it generated the single email address. I don't really understand how to receive uniq emails to my rails application now. I tried white labeling the `cloudmailin.net` in sendgrid but it doesn't work(may be am wrong here).

Googled a lot but didn't understand how to proceed from here. Can someone please help me in solving this issue. Appreciate if I get a good step-by-step reference

Answer (score 2):

There are two options to do this with CloudMailin.

**Option 1:**

On the free plan you can use a `+` in order to separate the email address given to you on CloudMailin and still create a unique email address that each customer can respond to. For example:

If you CloudMailin email address is `example1234@cloudmailin.net` you can use `example1234+unique_id_54321@cloudmailin.net`. CloudMailin calls `unique_id_54321` the disposable part of this email address. This way you can send an email out and state the sender of that email is `example1234+unique_id_54321@cloudmailin.net` and then tell one user from another.

**Option 2 (the better option):**

However, the best way to do this is to use CloudMailin's custom domains. You can then receive `anything@yourdomain.com`.

With custom domains enabled you set CloudMailin up to be your MX server. Then any email coming into `yourdomain.com` goes direct to CloudMailin (you can use `app.yourdomain.com` to avoid conflicts with your regular email if needed).

You can then send email out with the sender as `user-12345@yourdomain.com`, `task-12345@yourdomain.com` or any other unique identifier. When you receive the email from CloudMailin the envelope will show that the email was sent to `user-12345@yourdomain.com` and you can then use this to resolve who the user was.

Comment: If you need to try out custom domains on CloudMailin just contact support and they will arrange this for you.